# Multiple Inheritance in Python, same method in mature classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

What behaviour will provide Python if you have inheritance from many Classes, which have same method implemented?

```
Class A():
    def method():
        pass

Class B():
    def method():
        pass

Class C(A,B):
    pass
```

Comment: Have you simply tried doing this?

Comment: Look up the concept of "Method resolution order" (mro).

Comment: This depends also on the Python version; Python 2 or 3? If Python 2, does `A()` inherit from `object`?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite complex... there have been at least three different algorithms for Python method resolution order.

For simple cases it does what you expect, for the subtle differences see

See http://python-history.blogspot.it/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: Three? I only count two; old style and new style. Python 3 uses new-style by default, in Python 2 you need to inherit from `object` to do so. What is the third?

Comment: From the blog post of Guido: "Python has known at least three different MRO algorithms: classic, Python 2.2 new-style, and Python 2.3 new-style (a.k.a. C3)".

Comment: Ah, I generally ignore 2.2 new-style, as that was just one version and considered a bug. As of 2.3 onwards, there are just 2 variants, and you can generally assume that noone uses 2.2 anymore.